# How to use 2 Where conditions with Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following update query;

```
UPDATE service 
SET PathNameEn = (SELECT NameEn FROM service WHERE id = 430) + ' > '
```

I want to add another `WHERE` condition which is

```
WHERE id BETWEEN 430 AND 435
```

I tried:

```
UPDATE service 
SET PathNameEn = (SELECT NameEn FROM service 
                  WHERE id = 430 AND id BETWEEN 430 AND 435) + ' > '
```

But that didn't work

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain what "didn't work" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to update multiple rows?

```
UPDATE service
    SET PathNameEn = (SELECT NameEn + ' > ' FROM service WHERE id = 430)
    WHERE id between 430 AND 435;
```

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. 
Perfect, it works now Thank you. and I will accept the question but after 8 min